# Memory Exception when using Vidyo and Opentok SDK's in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, opentok, tokbox

I am using Vidyo and Opentok in my app for video call and other purpose.When I use Vidyo SDK and Opentok SDK separately they worked, but when I am trying include Vidyo and Opentok both SDK's in single app. I am getting Thread:

`BAD_ACCESS exception while initialising the Vidyo client  Library.` This error occurs only when I am using both Vidyo and Opentok in single app. Individually they are working fine. Any thoughts on what might be the reason.

Thanks.

[image: Check image]

This the screen shot the thread at the point of exception, I tried profiling with Zombie's but dint help. 
The stack trace is [image]

Comment: Could you share the entire call stack when the exception gets thrown?

Comment: @Ankur . Here is the link for the full stack trace http://pastebin.com/J7X8bbU9

Comment: this is the assembly code, not the stack trace. the stack trace should consist of a list of threads and have information about which thread crashed.

Comment: @Ankur I have updated the question with screenshot of stack trace. Thanks

Comment: What version of OpenTok SDK are you running? Earlier OpenTok versions had a precompiled OpenSSL that can cause collisions with other closed-source SDKs that also bundle OpenSSL (like Vidyo). You might also experiment with changing the order of initialization of the two libraries.

Comment: @wobbals I am using OpenTok iOS SDK 2.4, Can you explain about changing the order of initialiZation.Thanks.

Comment: @BalaChandra to change the order of initialization, try calling `[[OTSession alloc] initWithApiKey: token:]` before initializing the objects in the Vidyo SDK. if that doesn't work, try calling that method after initializing the objects in the Vidyo SDK.

Also, OpenTok iOS SDK version 2.4 is pretty old. The latest is version 2.7.1. Have you thought of updating?